# Redirect when deploying webapp using Spring Security on Tomcat server with custom domain

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat6

I developed a webapp (called "wander") using Spring and Spring security. When I run my web app on my development PC or deploy the webapp on a tomcat server where I host my website, the webapp works fine and redirects where the URL is http: //localhost:8080/wander to http: //localhost:8080/wander/login when I am not logged in. As expected, I am then redirected to root http://localhost:8080/wander upon login as the project root.

However, adjusting my vhosts file to use a custom domain, when I go to www.customdomain.com/wander as the project root or here if I am not logged in, "login" gets appended to the url where www.customdomain.com/wanderlogin appears as the URL and I then get a 404 missing page error. Why am I getting this error when I go to www.customdomain.com/wander or when I am not logged in, why does "login" get appended instead of going to www.customdomain.com/wander/login? I am not sure if this error is in my webapp itself or on the deployment server and how I have it configured. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful as I am newer to webapp development. I checked my Tomcat and Apache logs and no error seems related.

Dispatcher Servlet:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.togetherwander.web.controllers">
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource">

    <property value="com.togetherwander.web.messages.messages"
        name="basename" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
</bean>


<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/default.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Security-conext.xml:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query='select username, authority from users where binary username = ?'
            users-by-username-query='select username, password, enabled from users where binary username = ?'
            id="jdbcUserService" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createevent"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreateevent"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createwander"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/editevent"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/doeditevent"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/removetraveler"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/showwander"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/removewander"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/removeevent"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loggedout"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/loggedout" />
    <security:access-denied-handler
        error-page="/denied" />
    <security:remember-me key="offersAppKey"
        user-service-ref="jdbcUserService" />
</security:http>

<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>

<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

LoginController:

```
package com.togetherwander.web.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.togetherwander.web.dao.FormValidationGroup;
import com.togetherwander.web.dao.User;
import com.togetherwander.web.service.UsersService;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private UsersService usersService;

    @RequestMapping("/loggedout")
    public String showLoggedOut() {
        return "login";
    }

@Autowired
public void setUsersService(UsersService usersService) {
    this.usersService = usersService;
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String showLogin() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/newaccount")
public String showNewAccount(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "newaccount";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/createaccount", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount(@Validated(FormValidationGroup.class) User user, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "newaccount";
    }

    user.setAuthority("user");
    user.setEnabled(true);



    if(usersService.exists(user.getUsername())){
        result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username", "This username already exists!");
        return "newaccount";
    }


    try {
        usersService.create(user);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username");
        return "newaccount";
    }

    return "home";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it is always the simple answer. When my login controller was redirecting to the login jsp, unlike in my other webapps, I seem to have needed a forward slash in my proxy pass after the root: "/wander/" I still don't know why my Spring project required this but not my standard jsp and servlet projects.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /wander/ http://localhost:8080/wander/
ProxyPassReverse /wander/ http://localhost:8080/wander/
<Location "/sample">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```